# macOs Swift change minimize behavior?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nswindow

I'm trying to override the behavior of the minimize button on my `NSWindow` in my Cocoa macOS application.

The same way that you can use the

```
func windowShouldClose(_ sender: NSWindow) -> Bool
```

function from `NSWindowDelegate` to override the Exit button's behavior, I'd like to be able to customize what happens when the Minimize button is tapped.

Instead of minimizing, I'd like to cancel the minimize event and execute my own custom code.

I have found `windowWillMiniaturize(_ notification: Notification)` and `func windowDidMiniaturize(_ notification: Notification)`, however these don't allow me to cancel the event and replace it with my own custom code (from what I can see).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subclass `NSWindow` and override `miniaturize(_ sender: Any?)`.